# Enabling JMX on TIBCO BusinessWorks AppNode vs. BWAgent

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I was reading this TIBCO doc, https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.3.4/doc/html/GUID-BAC813F8-5DDC-4043-86D6-2F5D6C286B02.html, and it mentions this (emphasis mine):

Enable JMX on the ***AppNode or bwagent*** by adding the JMX properties in the ***AppNode or the agent TRA files*** for remote monitoring.

What are the pros/cons for enabling JMX on the AppNode versus the BWAgent?

FWIW, our system has 20 AppNodes spread across 2 servers (10 per server).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

To add JMX properties in an appnode, add the following line :
`java.extended.properties=-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:+UseParNewGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true` in the bwappnode-[APPNODE].tra file.

Or you can add it in the bwagent.tra, and all appnodes will inherit this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling JMX port on Appnode will let you see how the BWEngine has been performing, you could see memory and CPU utilization. And possibly you can have thread dumps.

BWAgent is mere like a hawk agent like in classic BW. I don't believe it helps much.